# On external port how to only close the output and wait for exit_status

Tags: erlang

Im using a port to run a pipeline with uncompresses and dd's some data:

```
Port = open_port({spawn, "bzcat | sudo dd of=/dev/foo}, 
                 [stream, use_stdio, exit_status]),
```

What I would like to do is produce a end-of-file situation on the output which causes the pipeline to complete and eventually exit.

I would like to wait for this completion and also capture the `exit_status`.

When I just call `port_close` it looks to me as if the pipeline is just terminated and there is no wait for completion.  Also I don't get any `exit_status` ....

How can I accomplish waiting for exit before my next step (which requires the dd to have completed).

Did some experiments and it looks like at least `port_close` doesn't kill the process, you just don't find out when its done.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to wait for spawned by `open_port` command to complete you need to wait for `exit_status` message:

```
1> Port = open_port({spawn, "sleep 7"}, [exit_status]).                   
#Port<0.497>
2> receive {Port, {exit_status, Code}} -> Code after 10000 -> timeout end.
0
```

**Update (about to say a port just close the output pipe):** I think you can't just close the output pipe with the default spawn driver. Default driver doesn't have any control commands and `port_close` although don't kill spawned command but completely erase all port's state.

Possible solutions:

- Write input stream to a file first and then run `bzip/dd` sequence on that file;
- Write your own driver or NIF (Maybe some open source implementations already exist?)
- Use some external script and control protocol, for example full (or chunk) length can be transferred before the actual content so the script will know when to close the connection

Comment: I use this method for the cases where the command terminates itself.  The pipeline (like many such Unix commands) only terminates when it is receiving end-of-file status on its input.  The only way I found to achieve this is `port_close` but then there won't be a exit_status message because the port is closed.

Comment: Ah, just understand the question

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting to the point giving up, unfortunately the workarounds you mention are either not possible -- whole reason I'm hassling myself with the port: can't write to file (too big) and the others are also not very appealing.  I think that this should be fixed in a standard way, just don't know yet what the most elegant solution would be.  Maybe gen_tcp's way of handling connections?

Comment: I guess NIF is a good way to go. In this case you can even remove all external dependencies later.

Answer (score 0):

Several rather ugly workarounds to this problem can be found here: [limitations of erlang:open_port() and os:cmd()](https://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-October/054157.html)

Some even use netcat to map the problem to a tcp connection.