# Use an OS process like a bash pipe: Send it STDIN and get its STDOUT

Tags: elixir, stdout, ipc, stdin, message-passing

I'm trying to use an [external process](https://github.com/nurse/nkf) which reads the STDIN, and writes to STDOUT.

I want to write the equivalent of this in Elixir, without using an [external library](https://hexdocs.pm/porcelain/) or wrapper script:

```bash
$ echo foo | nkf
foo
```

i.e. send data to `nkf` on stdin, and get the converted result back from `nkf`'s stdout, knowing that it has finished processing the stream.

I was trying to do this with ports, but the problem is a single sent message can be returned in multiple received messages, so there's no way to tell when the end of the message has been reached (simplified example, `"foo"` is a whole file in reality):

```elixir
iex(1)> port = Port.open({:spawn, "nkf -u"}, [:binary])
#Port<0.7>
iex(2)> Port.command(port, "foo")
true
iex(3)> flush
{#Port<0.7>, {:data, "fo"}}
{#Port<0.7>, {:data, "o"}}
:ok
```

How can I get the same bash pipe behaviour with Ports in Elixir?

Comment: is there a problem with using System.cmd/3?

Comment: What would be the issue with concatenating the data?

Comment: The [Port documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html) seems to cover this: you send the port a `:close` message, and it sends you a `:closed` message back when the process is exited.

Comment: @Daniel did you try it?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin the problem is that I don't know when the end of the input is.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'll have another look, but in my previous attempts closing closed the stream, which caused a broken pipe.

Comment: It looks like this bash behaviour is just not possible in the beam right now without extra help, although I'd like to believe otherwise! Here's an 11-year-old related Erlang question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570766/on-external-port-how-to-only-close-the-output-and-wait-for-exit-status

Comment: If what you want to do can be accomplished with C, C++, or Rust, another option is to write it in one of those languages and wrap it with a NIF. Rust makes this easy using a library called Rustler: https://github.com/rusterlium/rustler

Comment: @Jan yes that is also one of the suggestions on the linked question - however this question is for doing it using only the standard library.

Comment: A related question with some possible solutions in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76398478/how-to-use-a-port-synchronously-in-erlang?noredirect=1#comment134760832_76398478

Answer (score 2):

The beam does not currently provide a way to close the stream *to* the process and wait for the stream *from* the process to finish sending. Using ports, [closing the port](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_close-1) will also close the stream from the external process, even if the process has not finished sending data. Due to this, it is not currently possible to do using only built-in features - it's necessary to enlist the help of external tools like [porcelain](https://hexdocs.pm/porcelain/api-reference.html) or [erlexec](https://github.com/saleyn/erlexec).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:os.cmd("echo foo | nkf")`

Mentioned [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.9.1/System.html#cmd/3-shell-commands):

> Shell commands
> If you desire to execute a trusted command inside a shell, with pipes, redirecting and so on, please check :os.cmd/1.

Comment: Also [`System.shell/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#shell/2). This offloads the communication to the shell, which has different behaviour and is vulnerable to injection attacks as documented. What I want to do is to talk to the running process directly.