# How can I use a Port synchronously in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I want to make a synchronous call to a Port in Erlang. That is, to send some input to a running OS process connected through a Port and get its output directly, not using messages.

There is a `port_call` function which is said to do that. However, [the documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_call-3) says that the function parameters and return value are *driver-dependent*. I couldn't find any information about the driver which is used when a Port is opened the usual way, for example, by `open_port({spawn, 'cat'}, [binary])`.

I am coming from Elixir and the problem that I'm trying to solve is *concurrently* using a Port where a single external process is continuously running, taking input from and returning output to many VM processes (like a database).

I was looking for a mechanism in both Elixir and Erlang to guarantee that, if a Port is used asynchronously, its responses are delivered exactly to those processes that sent the corresponding requests.

It looks like the [solution that Erlang suggests](https://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html#erlang-program) is to call `receive` immediately after a `command` message is sent to the Port (probably relying on the fact that message ordering is guaranteed in Erlang), but this technique can't be used with Elixir's GenServer, since it [advises against it](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-receiving-regular-messages).

If there was a way to 'set a cookie' on a message to the Port and then get it back when it responds, it would be possible to match the response to the request, but I see no way doing that with Erlang at the moment.

The only solution I see is to add a decorator to the OS process which would pass this cookie from request to response, but it seems ugly.

I must be missing something here since both languages are very mature.

Comment: Link for mods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833431/use-an-os-process-like-a-bash-pipe-send-it-stdin-and-get-its-stdout

Comment: I think this is not fair. The question about organizing exchange with external processes is legitimate and there's not that much information on the subject out there, at least I couldn't find much.

Comment: The linked question above has been restored now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`erlexec`](https://github.com/saleyn/erlexec). It's much more flexible and capable than the built-in driver, and it might provide what you're looking for. For example, its [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/erlexec/readme.html) specifically provides [examples for running OS commands synchronously](https://hexdocs.pm/erlexec/readme.html#running-os-commands-synchronously).

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this, the library is great!
Unfortunately, according to the docs, interaction with a long-running process is still only possible via sending and receiving messages. The example that you linked is about one-off processes. That is, within a `exec:run` call an OS process starts, then its output is captured, and then the OS process exits.

Comment: And the scenario that I'd like to implement is as follows:
1. an OS process (a port) starts and keeps running in the background
2. an Erlang/Elixir process calls the process, passing the input, and gets the output synchronously, in a call
3. the OS process keeps running

Comment: I think you might need a way to attach a unique identifier to the input and have the OS process provide that identifier together with that input's output. If you have control over the implementation of the OS process, this should be straightforward, but if not, you can achieve it using an intermediate OS process that you control. But in general it's hard to answer your question without knowing more details of the OS process, such as where it gets input, where it sends output, and whether it already supports ways of avoiding mixing the output from multiple concurrent inputs.

Comment: Yes, I've also decided to go this way. I wish this feature would be built into Erlang, but it is what it is.
What the process does is, it basically takes an input line (newline-terminated) and outputs another line based on the input. Fortunately, if I add an identifier in front of the input line, the process will return it almost unchanged; this way I can match the response to the request, and thus, by keeping a map of identifiers and caller pids in GenServer's state, be able to know who to send the OS process' response.